# old plone 2.5 dump on mavericks or ubuntu 12.04

Tags: plone

i have a folder with an old plone version 2.5 and i would restore it on mac os mavericks or ubuntu 12.04. I know, that this really old plone version need python 2.4. I get it form python.org for mac os x but i don't found anything for ubuntu 12.04. I tried to restore this dump but it's not easy without a good documentation for version 2.5.
How can i restore this dump?

Comment: Dou you mean a zexp? you have to provide more informations. Your installation is up and running? Any Traceback while restore?

Comment: Hi, it looks like there is a cluster instance. I have a blank Plone 2.5.5 run successfully on the Mavericks. To start, I use "/ Applications/Plone-2.5.5/Instance/bin/zopectl start" but in the old dump, there is no zopectl. In the bin folder of the dump there zeopack, zeoserver and zopepy. The dump also has lots of Python eggs and Plone extensions, so that a simple copy of the Data.fs probably will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Start with an installer from https://launchpad.net/plone/2.5/2.5.5 . That will take care of not only Python, but also handle other binary components.

Install Plone on the target server, then transfer any custom add-on Plone products from the source server. Test it.

When that's running, copy the Data.fs file from the source to overwrite the Data.fs on the target.

Comment: Sorry, I think I've missed me. It is probably still a Plone 3 version. How do I get the Plone addons in the new instance? I have no buildout.cfg. And if I copy the Data.fs in the new instance I get in the log "Could not import class ofs.uninstalled xyz from module" when I go over the zope manager in the backend.

Comment: Take a look at http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/general-advice-on-updating-from-a-non-buildout-to-buildout-based-installation for strategies. You can find installers for old versions at http://launchpad.net/plone